# RequestLocationUpdates - update location if minDistance OR minTime

Tags: android, gps, tracking

I have tracking system and I'm using Android [RequestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) to get notified about user location changed. Method have parameters **minDistance** and **minTime**. Base logic is that notification is called when both of these parameters are met (minTime **AND** minDistance). I want to get notified for example if minTime **OR** minDistance is met.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and allowed to invoke `requestLocationUpdates()` multiple times.

So invoke it one time with your requested minTime and set minDistance to 0, and invoke it a second time minDistance set to your requested minDistance and minTime set to some small value or even 0.

You can pass the same PendingIntent to both calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the starting latitude and longitude and then in the

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}
```

you can grab the new values and then send them onto your method so that it can check the new values against the starting values.

As for the timing, you can start a timer at the begging as well, and have it be checked every certain time interval, or have it be checked at `onLocationChanged`